# How do I call an object as method parameter?

Tags: java, class, methods, parameters, return

Say, I wanna make a game. I introduced some characters (as a class), with health and damage parameters. Now I wanna create a method called "PerformHit" that would perform some attack. Like

```
class fight {
int PerformHit(object1,object2){

return object1.health - object2.damage;
 }
}
```

However, I cannot call an object as method parameter. How do I deal with that?

Comment: You have to give a name for your parameter (object1 paramName...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

java is fully typed. So type those parameters. `int performHit(Player player, Weapon weapon) { return player.health - weapon.damage; }`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class fight {
int PerformHit(Object object1, Object object2){

return object1.health - object2.damage;
 }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure "Object" doesn't have those properties.